# Simple solution for 3 circles (images) sitting horizontally equidistant apart and aligned

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So for 3 days all I've been trying to do is have:

- 3 images shaped into circles

  - sitting aligned horizontally, equal distance apart
  - taking up central 70% of the screen
  - where all heights and widths are based on `%` (so they adjust with resizing of the browsers)

It seems like such a simple task, but after 3 days and asking multiple questions, I'm getting nowhere. Please, can someone write me a code to achieve this?

If it helps, I have this circle code so far:

Thanks if you can help me

(I am new to coding)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
  body{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  }
/*Parallax*/

.parallax{
    background-image: url("bg.jpg");
    height: 540px; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    position:relative;
}
/*Parallax*/

#header{
 position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center;
 left: 20%;
  font-size: 4vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #357eca;
  width: 50%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;



}

h5
{   
  color:white; 
  text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-weight: 900;
 
  /*-webkit-margin-before:0.67em;
  -webkit-margin-after:0.67em;
  -webkit-margin-start:0px;
  -webkit-margin-end:0px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-colour:rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  -webkit-box-direction:normal;
  position: absolute;*/
}
h5:after, h5:before
{
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
/*--- Circular images --- */

.img-circular1,
.img-circular2,
.img-circular3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.img-circular1 {
  background-image: url('/Images/learn.jpg');
}

.img-circular2 {
  background-image: url('/Images/watch.jpg');
}

.img-circular3 {
  background-image: url('/Images/practice.jpg');
}

#container1 {
  top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
      height: 50vh;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.wrap {

width: 30%;
  height:50%;
}

.flex {
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex > div {
  flex: 0 0 23%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="navigation"></div>

<div class="parallax"><h5 id="header"><b>Welcome to RyanTeaches</b></h5></div>

<!--<img src="bg.jpg" style="top:60px;height: 510px;min-width: 100%;">-->
<div id="content">
<h2 style="margin-top: 0px;">Activities</h2>
</div>
<div id="container1">
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="img-circular1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="img-circular2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="img-circular3"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content" style="margin-top: 100px;">
<p style="padding-bottom: 300px;">Helllllloooooooooo</p>

</div>

<script src="nav.js"></script>
<script src="template.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML?

Comment: You need to add your HTML code too, otherwise we cannot see what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: I'm thinking a sketch of the behaviour you wish for would also be beneficial, at least to me it's not 100% clear how exactly you want the images to be positioned and what's supposed to be 70%?

Comment: I have posted all my current code, but I feel it may all be redundant since I have been messing with it all day and cant seem to get perfect circles aligned centrally under the heading "activities" that resize, and stay cirles when I resize the browser.

Comment: The nearest I have come, is managing to get perfect circles aligned when the browser is full size, but then when I resize, they become ovals. I set body height and width to 100% and I thought my percentages would then work fine, but everything just entirely disappeared for the umteenth time.

Comment: Don't start pulling your hair, in a few months you'll laugh about it (eventually). We have all been there! (were's my wig...)

Comment: Add `* { outline: 1px dashed }` to your CSS. It will help you to 'see' the mess you're in. ;)

Comment: I now have dots around everything?

Comment: Yes, it is just a little helper showing what sizes your elements are. (not part of the answer)

Comment: Ooh I see, thank you, that will come in handy

Comment: I am working on this too, it's a nice little s.o.b. of a question, what I need to know: are your images square in size or can they be any ratio and/or size?

Comment: They are square in size, and I use the code to make them circular

Comment: In the .wrap part - I found the maximum width I can have there is around 20% otherwise it starts to repeat the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should come close to a satisfactory solution. I optimized some code and used shorthand notation where possible and introduced class `.band` as a generic container with default values. The `.band` content will give it it's final height.

Also, to get a nice circle I introduced a responsive **width** and **height** constraint for the images. This is necessary to force images of any arbitrary size to fit nicely in a circle (check the sizes of the dummy images!)

`height: calc(0.2 * 100vmin)` will result in an circle of 64px at a minimum viewport size of 320px smoothly resizing to 256px at a minimum viewport size of 1280px, called responsive sizing.

I commented the code for as far I deemed relevant, let me know if you need more explanation or just want to pick my brain (caution: it is a bit of a mess up there).

```css
body {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0; /* remove nasty space around our page */
}

#navigation {
  color: #357eca;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#parallax {
  background-image: url("bg.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#parallax>div {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 50px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 -60px;
}

#header {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 15px 5% 20px 5%;
  background-color: #357eca;
  opacity: 0.9;

  font-size: 4vw;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

h5 {   
  color:white; 
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.band { /* Nice grey'ish band as container */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #eee;

  max-width: 100vw; /* stay in horizontal view */

  /* padding moves all content to center 70% of <body> */
  padding: 2rem 15%; /* 100% - 2 * 15% = 70% width */

  /* extra top/bottom spacing for clarity */
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

#container1 {
  justify-content: space-around; /* evenly space the images on the line */
}
[class^="img-circular"] {
  height: calc(0.2 * 100vmin); /* 64px at 320 and 256px at 1280 */
  width : calc(0.2 * 100vmin); /* nice responsive sizing */

  background-position: center;  /* center image in parent */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* prevents repeat of image! */
  background-size: cover;       /* stretch/shrink to fill */

  border-radius: 50%;
}
.img-circular1 { background-image: url("http://placehold.it/237x334") }
.img-circular2 { background-image: url("http://placehold.it/317x123") }
.img-circular3 { background-image: url("http://placehold.it/141x301") }
```

```html
<div id="navigation" class="band">
        <p>navigation</p>
    </div>

    <div id="parallax" class="band">
        <div></div>
        <h5 id="header">
            <b>Welcome to RyanTeaches</b>
        </h5>
        <div></div>
    </div>

    <div class="band content">
        <h2>Activities</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="container1" class="band">
        <div class="img-circular1"></div>
        <div class="img-circular2"></div>
        <div class="img-circular3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="band content">
        <p>Helllllloooooooooo</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi - thank you so much! That is almost perfect and exactly what I want - the only 2 things - I wanted my picture starting direct from the nav bar, and I've fixed that in, but I also only want that "grey container" band to be 70% in width centralised - which part of the code would I alter to implement that? Currently it takes 100% of the width. Tried changing 100vw to 70vs with margin-left/right: auto; but that didnt seem to have an effect

Comment: Actually - dont worry about that bit, I added in a left and right side bar with a white bckground taking up 15% each on the left and right, so the grey and only appears on the central 70% anyway. Last tax for this page is I need to add a heading underneath each of the pictures (Learn, watch, practice) where each heading is centrally aligned with it respective circle

Comment: I was actually hoping you'd pick up where I left off and so you did. CSS and flexbox can be a lot of fun (and a massive pain too, given the many options). But the bare basic is: what do I need? **a row of columns or a column of rows?**, each nested level again.

Comment: BTW, add a container of 70% width to any `.band` and make the `band:background-color` equal to `body:background-color` and you should get what you need. Look at the band as some garbage container, and modify its content to meet your requirements

Comment: Why don't you fiddle with `<figure>` instead of `<div>` for the images. That tag already incorporates a mechanism for placing a header beneath an image. Might just be what you need. **AND** don't forget to close your question by marking it answered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flex` with `justify-content` to either `space-between` or `space-around` (or `space-evenly` - a new property that isn't well supported, only works in firefox) depending on what you mean by having the elements equidistant apart (read more about that property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)). Set a `flex-basis` on the flex children to establish their width, then nest your elements with the background inside of the flex child so you can use `padding-bottom: 100%` to make the element as tall as it is wide so that it's a square - or a perfect circle with your border radius.

```css
#container1 {
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#container1 > div {
  flex: 0 0 23%;
}

.img-circular1,
.img-circular2,
.img-circular3 {
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.img-circular1 {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C22p.jpg');
}

.img-circular2 {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBNlv.png?s=328&g=1');
}

.img-circular3 {
  background-image: url('http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/lazyfonz2.png');
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="navigation"></div>

<div class="parallax"><h5 id="header"><b>Welcome to RyanTeaches</b></h5></div>

<!--<img src="bg.jpg" style="top:60px;height: 510px;min-width: 100%;">-->
<div id="content">
<h2 style="margin-top: 0px;">Activities</h2>
</div>

<div id="container1">
    <div><div class="img-circular1"></div></div>
    <div><div class="img-circular2"></div></div>
    <div><div class="img-circular3"></div></div>
</div>

<div id="content" style="margin-top: 100px;">
<p style="padding-bottom: 300px;">Helllllloooooooooo</p>

</div>

<script src="nav.js"></script>
<script src="template.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I have updated my question with all my code for this page - will your code work with my current code if I just add it in?

Comment: @RyanBrown You'll have to wrap each of your circles with another `div` element and copy and paste the CSS.

Comment: @ChrisHappy thanks for the assist sir! I was just putting all of that in. I appreciate it. And haha, needed an extra pic, and your avatar is great :)

Comment: <div class="flex">
<div id="container1">
<div>
    <div class="img-circular1"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <div class="img-circular2"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <div class="img-circular3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

Like that?

Comment: @RyanBrown chris (like a boss) updated my post with your code. You don't need the `.flex` parent - he applied the flex properties to `#container` in your css.

Comment: So what should I do now?

Comment: @RyanBrown add it to your site's code? accept a solution to your question here? not sure what you mean...

Comment: I havent got a solution yet? I currently still have 0 circle images showing on the page

Comment: Not fully - I have updated my question with the exact code I am currently using. I now have 3 equally spaced circular-sort of images. But they do not stay circles. When I maximise my browser, they are ovals. Also, when I maximise, the image starts to repeat itself